# Only run gulp for browserify

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, browserify, vue.js

I have a gulpfile.js with a bunch of css, js and Vue.  I would like to run gulp with a flag or something that will only run browserify so I don't have to sit around and wait for css and js files to compile that I don't need to worry about.  I know about gulp watch, but I'd like to use a flag and just run gulp if possible.  Something like:

```
$ gulp -browserify
```

Would be nice.  Thanks!

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
mix.sass('app.scss')
    .browserify('main.js')
```

Comment: Just run whatever task is set to run browserify, eg `gulp browserify`. Without seeing your `gulpfile.js`, it's difficult to provide any more information

Comment: @Phil - check it out.  I added relevant part of gulpfile.  I think you may have just answered my question though.  Make an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Where are your gulp tasks?

Comment: You can see my entire gulpfile.js here:  https://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/jf2qb0rf/

Comment: There's absolutely no use of gulp here. I suggest you read the documentation ~ https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: You should use the traditional `gulp.task(name, fn)` way of doing things. Then type `gulp taskname`. Right now it looks like gulp is simply executing  the code within Gulpfile.js